# RMagick crop! "bignum too big to convert into `long'" error

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I'm getting an error from RMagick 2.13.1 on rare occasions and the error message doesn't make sense to me.  Can anyone shed any insight?

```
pagination = Magick::ImageList.new
pagination.from_blob(RestClient.get(url))
pagination.each do |f| 
  f.crop!(Magick::SouthWestGravity, 0, 20, 368, 358) 
end
```

`crop!` raises a `RangeError: bignum too big to convert into 'long'` Prior to calling `crop!` I can inspect `f` and get "PNG 550x366 550x366+0+0 DirectClass 16-bit 625kb".

The code generally works and I can't figure out what is causing it to break on this image.